# Add label to graphic icon in GraphicsLayer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-online

I am using the following code to create a GraphicsLayer:

```
 const labelClass= { 
      symbol: { type: "text", color: "green", font: { family: "Sans", size: 12, weight: "bold"  }},
            labelPlacement: "above-center"
            };
gl=new GraphicsLayer({ labelingInfo: [labelClass]})
app.map.add(app.gl);
```

And then adding icons to it using this code:

```
let graphic=new Graphic(
     geometry:{ type: "point", lat, lon },      
     symbol:{ type: "picture-marker", url:"popover.png", width:19, height:13 },
     });
gl.add(graphic);
```

How do I tell arcGIS what text to draw with each icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GraphicsLayer` doesn't have `labelingInfo` property. For labeling you need to use `FeatureLayer`, in fact since the new library version it is recommended to use `FeatureLayer`, that is basically you need to use it for almost all cases that you could use `GraphicsLayer` in older library versions.

[ArcGIS API - GraphicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-GraphicsLayer.html)

> It is generally preferred to construct a FeatureLayer with its source property when working with client-side graphics since the FeatureLayer has more capabilities than the GraphicsLayer, including rendering, querying, and labeling.

So, returning to the question, you could use `labelExpressionInfo` property to bind the label text you want to display to the value of an attribute of the features. Something like this,

```
labelExpressionInfo: {
 expression: "$feature.NAME"
}
```

Where `NAME` is the attribute you want to use as label.